# Datepicker jQuery not working in IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
var selector = function (dateStr) {
        var d1 = $('.fromdate').datepicker('getDate');
        var d2 = $('.todate').datepicker('getDate');
        $('.fromdate').datepicker("option", "maxDate",d2);           
        $('.todate').datepicker("option", "minDate",d1);  
        var diff = 1;
        if (d1 && d2) {
            diff = diff + Math.ceil((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000);
        }
        $('.calculated').val(diff);
        $('.minim').val(d1)
    }
$('.fromdate').datepicker({
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "images/calendar_year.png",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
                dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                minDate: 0
});
$('.todate').datepicker({ 
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar_year.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
                dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                minDate: ($(".fromdate").is(":visible") && $(".todate").html() != ""? $('.todate').datepicker('getDate'): 'null'),
});
$('.fromdate,.todate').change(selector)
});
</script>
```

It worked nice but yesterday I got a call from somebody saying that it is not working in IE 7. I found two symptoms:
- any parameters makes the calendar to not appear. It works only like this

```
$('.fromdate').datepicker({
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: I see `minDate: ($(".fromdate").is(":visible") && $(".todate").html() != ""? $('.todate').datepicker('getDate'): 'null'),` remove comma at the end. I am not sure but seems thats the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : use index `0` for all class selector for `minDate` value as it returns array. And remove last comma.

```
$('.todate').datepicker({ 
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar_year.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
                dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                minDate: ($(".fromdate:first").is(":visible") && $(".todate:first").html() != ""? $('.todate:first').datepicker('getDate'): 'null')

});
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, `$(".fromdate")[0]` will return you DOM object and they don't have `is()` method. In short this will throw error.